# WHERE clause not working with Visual Studio rdlc reports

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, phpmyadmin, rdlc

I am having an issue with my one report (Visual Studio rdlc reports) query where there is permanently an issue with the `where` clause when I try filter the results by date from the Invoice table:

```
SELECT tblItem.ItemName, tblSale.Qty, tblInvoice.InvoiceID, tblItem.Price * tblSale.Qty
FROM     tblInvoice INNER JOIN
                  tblSale ON tblSale.InvoiceID = tblInvoice.InvoiceID INNER JOIN
                  tblItem ON tblItem.ItemID = tblSale.ItemID
GROUP BY tblInvoice.InvoiceID

WHERE tblInvoice.Date >= {^@theDate}
```

This above query runs perfectly in PhpMyAdmin on cpanel with our tables but as I put it into the query in .rdlc reports then it throws the error.

I have another query to populate another report where I use exactly the same where clause and it filters without an issue. The working where clause uses the date column from the same table that the select calls from:

```
SELECT CustID, FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Email FROM tblCustomer 
WHERE DateAdded >= @theDate
```

Is there any solution to this? 
Also are you able to do equations in the query for .rdlc reports?
I need a "total" column which would be `(tblSales.Qty * tblItem.Price)` which again works perfectly in PhpMyAdmin but will not display any value when run in the .rdlc report.

Github Link: https://github.com/byroncoetsee/WIL2014

The set I am having problems with is `Dataset3` and then `frmReportSales`, `frmShowingSales` where the date value is passed across.

Comment: What is the error? Also, while I don't know specifically how mySql works, the query would not be valid in MSSQL due to the `Group By` statement, which is only supposed to be used for aggregation.

Comment: Always says that there is an error around the Where clause, I removed the group by and only had the where clause and immediately threw an error

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? Just saying there is an error is not as helpful as it could be.

Comment: Error in query near WHERE '>'

Comment: Ha the dreaded generic SQL error. It's definitely an issue with your query. Try eliminating the braces and carrot from your parameter. As well as the group by.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that WHERE clause has to come first. Before GROUP BY: [mySql GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

more here: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)